# Why nebular behaves different across various browsers?

Tags: angular, frontend, web-deployment, nebular, browser-support

I am using a **nebular theme** for my angular application. It works fine for laptops as expected.

But when comes to **mobile devices**, The padding behaves differently **for different browsers**.

For Example, I am using a **REDMI 9 power mobile** to view my application with various browsers,

**1) Chrome browser:**

```
     The border-spacing is not displayed as expected as below:
```

[image]

**2) OperaMini Browser :**:

```
    In operaMini, the application spacing is fine as expected like below image:
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

If I use another mobile like **Redmi Note 8 pro**  to view the same application It works fine even in the chrome browser itself as in the below image.

[image]

So I am very confused about how to solve this issue. Someone, please guide me to solve or at least what happens? Thanks in advance